# Syntax for getting a model field value in kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i am new to kendo and i am using kendo UI in Asp MVC and using the kendo grid for it . in the client template i am having a HTML template with different conditions now i want to check for the value from a session and set up template OR simply show the fields value e.g. `Status` that i have already . Below is my client template part.

```
.ClientTemplate("#if('" + Session["_UserType"].ToString() + "'!= 'sub'){#" + "<div><a href='javascript:' onclick=\"Create()\"><input type='button' value='Confirm' id='btnDone' class='btn' title='Confirm' />" + "#}else{#" + "<div>Pending</div>" + "#}}else{#Status#}#")
```

But it shows nothing with errors (possibly syntax error) which i cant track where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use #=status# to show your field value e.g. i your case it will be

```
else{##=Status##}#"
```